# Saved project into JAR and Errors occur... perfect running it through NetBeans

Tags: java, database, netbeans, jar

I've got an application with database connection etc, which is working correctly in NetBeans, although I want to test the application on different PC etc... so I've created a Jar File, and somehow when opening it it gives an error, straight after trying to connect to the database I'm guessing as GUI is functioning although I can't retrieve or save any data to the database. What could be the problem?

```
public View_HomePage() {
        initComponents();
        String date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").format(new Date());
               lblDate.setText(date);

        String[][] rowData = new String[0][4];
        String[] columns = {"ID", "Name", "Surname", "Registration", "Make", "Model", "Engine", "Year", "Mileage", "Type", "Date", "Time", "Postcode", "Number"};
        resultModel = new DefaultTableModel(rowData,columns);
        jTable1.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true); 

         try{
            Model_Customer[] appointment = Controller_ManageCustomer.FindCustomers2(lblDate.getText());
            resultModel.setRowCount(0);
            for(int i = 0; i < appointment.length; i++)
                resultModel.insertRow(i,new Object[]{appointment[i].GetID(),appointment[i].GetFName(), appointment[i].GetLName(), appointment[i].GetRegistration(), appointment[i].GetMake(), appointment[i].GetModel(), appointment[i].GetEngine(), appointment[i].GetYear(), appointment[i].GetMileage(), appointment[i].GetType(), appointment[i].GetDate(), appointment[i].GetTime(), appointment[i].GetPostcode(), appointment[i].GetNumber()});

         if (jTable1 == null) {
        jTable1 = new JTable(resultModel);
        add(new JScrollPane(jTable1));
    } else {
        jTable1.setModel(resultModel);
    }

}
         catch(Exception ex){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,ex.getMessage(),"Error Problem",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }

    }
```

Error in CMD shows as =

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Users\IMPREZA>cd Documents

C:\Users\IMPREZA\Documents>cd attachments

C:\Users\IMPREZA\Documents\attachments>java -jar LPGExerts.jar
ClassNotFoundException: org.postgresql.Driver
Fatalnull
null


Import java.sql.*;
import java.util.concurrent.*;

public class Database 
{
    private static Connection con;
    private static String url = "jdbc:postgresql://lpgexperts.heliohost.org:5432/*****";
    private static String user = "****";
    private static String pass = "***"
    static{
        try{
            Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver"); 
            Database.con = DriverManager.getConnection(Database.url, Database.user, Database.pass);
        }
        catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {System.err.println("ClassNotFoundException: " + ex.getMessage());}
        catch (SQLException ex)           {System.err.println("SQLException: " + ex.getMessage());}

        //Ping every minute, keep alive

        // Create a service with 3 threads.
        ScheduledExecutorService execService = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(3);

        // Schedule a task to run every 5 seconds with no initial delay.
        execService.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try{
                    Connection c = Database.GetConnection();
                    Statement stmt = c.createStatement();
                    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT 1");
                }catch(Exception e){
                    System.out.println("Fatal" + e.getMessage());
                    System.out.println(e.getCause());
                }
            }
        }, 0L, 60L, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

    /**
     * Get connection interface
     * 
     * @return Connection instance
     */
    public static Connection GetConnection(){
        return Database.con;
    }
```

Update: Made it Work!!! Opened project properties in NetBeans... and found that in Libraries there was nothing about PGDriver... added the driver to the library saved and compiled the jar file and woop woop works :)

Comment: what is the error? how do you 'open' your jar?

Comment: Opening it with Java Runtime Environment (double click)

Comment: What is the Error ?? i think u have hard coded some thing.. Now Are you running on some other machine or on same machine?

Comment: Running on the same machine, database is on a server, it just doesnt want to connect to it

Comment: ok can u copy paste that error or exception message here

Comment: The error is what u see from the code above, it catches an exception with the message that i put myself... so not helping at all lol.

Comment: We cant help u until unless u give usthe exact exception message.

Comment: As you can see from above code, Im trying to add a row to the table from the database to a JTable, which if is a null throws an exception.. so its a null pointer exception I cant give u an exact exception message! as app works in Netbeans but via JAR well.. it only shows the optionpane and its error message that i create myself

Comment: Hi after opening jar in CMD the error is = Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Users\IMPREZA>cd Documents

C:\Users\IMPREZA\Documents>cd attachments

C:\Users\IMPREZA\Documents\attachments>java -jar LPGExerts.jar
ClassNotFoundException: org.postgresql.Driver
Fatalnull
null

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the PostGresql driver on your classpath when you run it as a jar on a different machine.

Say your driver jar is named pg.jar. It is kept at -

```
c:\Users\IMPREZA\Documents\jars
```

then

```
C:\Users\IMPREZA\Documents\attachments>java -classpath c:\Users\IMPREZA\Documents\jars\pg.jar;. -jar LPGExerts.jar
```

Update: Even though you are running it on same machine, do specify classpath. It should work. 
Try it and let me know.

Update 2: >> but how can i run the jar then not from cmd but by double click?

NetBeans adds the jar to your classpath before running it. You have added the driver jar to the project in NetBeans. Let me know the result!

Update 3:

Yes. do check the spellings. Make sure you use double quotes for paths that contain spaces.

Try this -

```
java -classpath C:\Users\IMPREZA\Documents\attachments\lib\postgresql-9.2-1002.jdbc4.jar;.\LPGExerts.jar -jar LPGExerts.jar
```

with quotes (just a shot, no need since I dont see spaces in paths)

```
java -classpath "C:\Users\IMPREZA\Documents\attachments\lib\postgresql-9.2-1002.jdbc4.jar;.\LPGExerts.jar" -jar LPGExerts.jar
```

Update 4:

Now, i cant say anything. has to be a spelling mistake. Check all spellings, paths, etc.

1. Use the exact same jar as in Netbeans, and remember to update your -classpath argument to match the file name of the jar you added to your project in Netbeans. I am just making sure that we have a working jar in classpath. The jar you added in Netbeans is working.
2. Make sure your LPGExerts.jar is being rebuilt after every code change you made.

Do let me know if you find a solution.

Update 5:
You are welcome

Comment: but how can i run the jar then not from cmd but by double click?

Comment: C:\Users\IMPREZA\Documents\attachments> java -classpath C:\Users\IMPREZA\Documen
ts\attachments\lib\postgresql-9.2-1002.jdbc4.jar;. -jar LPGExerts.jar
ClassNotFoundException: org.postgresql.Driver
Fatalnull
null

Comment: or is there something I have misstyped?

Comment: Both ways same error C:\Users\IMPREZA\Documents\attachments>java -classpath "C:\Users\IMPREZA\Docume
ts\attachments\lib\postgresql-9.2-1002.jdbc4.jar;.\LPGExerts.jar" -jar LPGExert
.jar
ClassNotFoundException: org.postgresql.Driver


C:\Users\IMPREZA\Documents\attachments>java -classpath C:\Users\IMPREZA\Document
s\attachments\lib\postgresql-9.2-1002.jdbc4.jar;.\LPGExerts.jar -jar LPGExerts.j
ar
ClassNotFoundException: org.postgresql.Driver

Comment: Now, i cant say anything. has to be a spelling mistake. do check if the jar is actually present.

Comment: checked the driver = C:\Program Files (x86)\NetBeans 7.4\ide\modules\ext\postgresql-9.2-1002.jdbc4.jar  so its same... Havent changed code as nothing to change, just have to make jar run lol... checked spelling, all correct (cmd tab button helps not to make mistakes)

Comment: Made it Work!!! Opened project properties in NetBeans... and found that in Libraries there was nothing about PGDriver... added the driver to the library saved and compiled the jar file and woop woop works :)

Comment: But then how was it compiling when the driver was not in the library?

Comment: It seems that NetBeans, has got a pure Database connection properties that works with the Project itself (There are two submenus Files / Services) in Services driver was set up. in Files there is a project were in library drivers wasn't there... doesnt make sense but finally works

Comment: Cool :) I have not seen anything like that in Eclipse. Probably you were exporting the jar via Netbeans, and not using an ant build script. And it would create a Classpath entry in the Manifest file. Sounds like that.

Comment: Yeah, seems so... :) Really appreciate you trying to help!